# How to control animate function on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have two divs named "arrow" and "inner". I am trying to control the animate slide function when the div is clicked but have been unfortunate. The issue is noticeable when clicking very fast on the "arrow" div after user stops clicking the div is still sliding.  I set the animate function under a small delay but I still experience lag. Here is my example code:

```
     <script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
          var out = 0;
          $("#arrow").click(function(){
          if(out==0)
            {
              $("#inner").animate({marginRight: "0px"}, 500 );
              out=1;
            }
        else
           {
             $("#inner").delay(400).animate({marginRight: "-100px"}, 500 );
             out=0;
           }
        });
    });
    </script>

    <div style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); height: 300px; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
<div id="inner" style="height: 100px; width: 150px; background-color: rgb(0, 204, 102); float: right; margin-right:-150px;" >Form is here</div>

<div id="arrow" style="height: 100px; width: 50px; background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); float: right; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;" >Arrow is here</div>


    </div>
```

Comment: 1) use 1.7.1 or latest -  2) why not toggle?

Comment: hey Use this - http://jsfiddle.net/paL6M/2/ (using accordion) BUT the **version you go is in here:** http://jsfiddle.net/VuzdM/1/ reside here - let me know if this helps, I can't see any lag let me know I can set it to answer and + 1 for @mplungjan for mentioning of using latest Jquery version , cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your code

```
$("#inner").animate({marginRight: "0px"}, 500 );
```

to

```
$("#inner").stop(true, true).animate({marginRight: "0px"}, 500 );
```

and

```
$("#inner").animate({marginRight: "-100px"}, 500 );
```

to

```
$("#inner").stop(true, true).animate({marginRight: "-100px"}, 500 );
```

Please see following Link for example :  http://jsfiddle.net/UAYTw/1/

you can also use $("#inner").stop(true, false).animate() instead of $("#inner").stop(true, true).animate(). as per your choice.

Comment: Thank you sir, that helped alot to keep it in control.

Comment: @user1261800- if this answer is helped alot then accept this answer necessary. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91889/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-to-my-questions

Answer (score 1):

Using Ravi's code props to him - toggle is cleaner in my opinion

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/eMsQr/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#arrow").toggle(
    function(){
      $("#inner").stop(true, true).animate({marginRight: "0px"}, 500 );
    },
    function(){
      $("#inner").stop(true, true).animate({marginRight: "-100px"}, 500 );
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.animate().stop()` method to stop the animation.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YKn7c/

Answer (score 0):

this may help:

```
        $("#button").hover(
            function () {
                $("#effect").stop().animate({ opacity: '1', height: '130' }, 300);
            },
            function () {
                $("#effect").stop().animate({ opacity: '0', height: '130' }, 300);
            }
        );
```

edited:

If You dont want to be closed:

```
         $("#button").hover(
            function () {
                $("#effect").stop().animate({ opacity: '1', height: '130' }, 300);
            },
            null
        );
```

Comment: I do not see any need for hover here. The OP wants to click

Comment: @mplungjan you're right, I copy and paste it from one of my projects.

Comment: @VahidHassani: I think i will implement the hover.  It will be very helpful. The only thing is how did you keep the sliding div open after the hover function was triggered? Here is a copy of my work http://jsfiddle.net/eMsQr/6/

Comment: You should put null for the mouse out part like the above I will edit the post.